# How can I add a group by to a hasMany relationship in laravel 5.3?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an elquent model named `Conversation`.

In that model I define a `hasMany` relationship on an eloquent model `CallParticipant` like so:

```
public function participants(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Purecloud\Analytics\CallParticipant', 'conversationId', 'conversationId');
}
```

Now, `CallParticipants` can be system processes, customers, or agents. I need a list of all the `CallParticipants` that are considered "agents" so I defined another relation like this:

```
public function agents(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Purecloud\Analytics\CallParticipant', 'conversationId', 'conversationId')
            ->whereIn('partPurpose', ['agent','user']);
}
```

Now, an "agent" can be a "participant" multiple times on a "conversation" that is to say there can be multiple rows for the same agent just with a different participantId, like this:

```
+----------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
| conversationId | participantId | partUserName | partPurpose |
+----------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
|              1 |           100 | Alex         | agent       |
|              1 |           101 | Mary         | agent       |
|              1 |           102 | Alex         | agent       | <-- I want to exlcude this
+----------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I need to remove these sortof-duplicates so that the relationship only returns one row for each `partUserName` (one row for Mary, and one row for Alex).

I tried to do this by adding a groupBy like this:

```
public function agents(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Purecloud\Analytics\CallParticipant', 'conversationId', 'conversationId')
        ->whereIn('partPurpose', ['agent','user'])
        ->groupBy('partUserName');
}
```

But this produces the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'analytics.callParticipants.participantId' isn't in GROUP BY

I also tried doing it in the `with` statement like below, but I get the same error:

```
$conversations = Conversation::with(
        [
            'agents' => function($query){
                $query->groupBy('partUserName');
            }
        ])
        ->get();
```

Is there any way I can limit the relationship to only rows with unique `partUserName`

Comment: Did you find any solution for this, Please let me know??

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way to do this is by "hacking" the relation. Could you try:

```
public function agents(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Purecloud\Analytics\CallParticipant', 'conversationId', 'conversationId')
    ->whereIn('partPurpose', ['agent','user'])
    ->latest(); 
}
```